# Grant monitor on snowflake task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I am trying to grant the `monitor` privilege on all current and future tasks in a snowflake database to a particular role.

[The documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#task-privileges) offers no examples.

I tried `GRANT MONITOR ON ALL TASKS ON DATABASE MY_DB TO ROLE ROLE_OVER`

Is something like that possible?  Do you have to go schema by schema?  Individual task by task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**IN** instead of **ON**):

```
GRANT MONITOR ON ALL TASKS IN DATABASE MY_DB TO ROLE ROLE_OVER
;
```